# Highcharts stacked columns with drilldown

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a stacked chart with drilldown, but I set the data has "data, data2", can I change this and do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/FWHGx/

```
var data = [[
    {
        name:'Recomendación',
        y:28, 
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
            name:['Recomendación','Area de Oportunidad','Observación'],
            type:'column',
            categories:['Geofísica','Geología','Petrofísica'],
            data:[[
                {name:'Txt 1',y:28, color: colors[0]},
                {name:'Txt 2',y:30, color: colors[0]}
            ]]
        }
    },
    {name:'Recomendación',y:30, color: colors[0]}
],
[
    {name:'Area de Oportunidad',y:3, color: colors[1]},
    {name:'Area de Oportunidad',y:5, color: colors[1]}
],
[
    {name:'Observación',y:1, color: colors[2]},
    {name:'Observación',y:2, color: colors[2]}
]];
```

Instead of this: http://jsfiddle.net/NULTY/410/

```
data = [{ 
    y: 55.11}
    }, {
        y: 21.63
    }],
data2 = [{
        y: 21.63
        }, { 
    y: 55.11
    }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open console, and follow errors. If you will fix them one by one, you will get properly working code. For example you are missing `chart` variable, or `color` variable is missing (again..).

Some of errors are fixed, the rest is up to you: http://jsfiddle.net/FWHGx/2/